# Delete/create scheduled task

Tags: events, active-directory, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem in Windows Server 2012 r2.
It seems that I cannot delete or create with the same name a scheduled task.

[image]

I couldn't find any help searching on Internet so now I am asking you guys. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When are you ever allowed to create a file with the same name? That would be like naming your son Pandoranum - how would anybody tell the two of you apart?

Comment: take a closer look at the picture....and then you'll understand.....

Answer (score 0):

it seems that I forgot to search in system32/tasks/event viewer tasks - my bad, should I delete this post ?